Connection error whe configuring postgresql_basebackup in nxs-backup
when configuring postgresql_basebackup in nxs-backup I encountered the following:
PSQL connect error: pq: database "repluser" does not exist
Tried to edit pg_hba.conf, but it still doesn't work
postgresql_basebackup.conf:
job_name: test-postgresql_basebackup
type: postgresql_basebackup
tmp_dir: /data/nxs-backup
safety_backup: false
deferred_copying: false
sources:
  - name: psql_basebackup
    connect:
      db_host: localhost
      db_port: "5432"
      psql_ssl_mode: require
      db_user: repluser
      db_password: ******
    target_dbs:
    - all
    excludes:
    - postgres
    - template0
    - template1
    gzip: true
storages_options:
  - storage_name: aws
    backup_path: /nxs-backup/
    retention:
      days: 7
      weeks: 0
      months: 0

